# H2 Get Date 1 day old from current time

Tags: sql, h2

I'm currently working on a really fun problem. I want to get a date that is one day old (from current date) and then compare it to now.

The exact way to do this in PostreSQL is this:

```
 select * from table WHERE date < now() - '1 day'::interval;
```

How do I do this in H2 JDBC? Does anybody know?

Grateful for any assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply subtract the number of days from `current_date`

```
select *
from the_table
where the_date_column < current_date - 1;
```

The above would work in Postgres just as well.

Comment: Hey, This doesn't seem to return any result. Is -1 really a day in this case?

Comment: @PrinceofSweden: yes it is. Today is 2017-12-11 and if I run `select current_date - 1` it returns 2017-12-10 (h2 version 1.4.196). Is your "date" column a timestamp maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [DATEADD](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd) function. It works for addition and subtraction:

```
 select * from table WHERE date < DATEADD('DAY', -1, CURRENT_DATE);
```